# New and Delete Operator?

Tags: c, syntax-highlighting, new-operator, delete-operator

What i'm asking now is, what does the `delete` and `new` operator do in C? I asked this question, when I was just simply thinking about how to allocate memory in C++, and I remembered you use the `new` and `delete` keyword, (`malloc()` and `free()` in C). But when I type in the `new` and `delete` keyword in a `.c` file. It showed up as a keyword. What exactly is the keywords use in C(Not C++).

```
UsbDriver *ud = malloc(sizeof(UsbDriver));
free(ud);
new // What is this keyword?(C)
delete // What is this keyword?(C)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using an editor that supports C and C++. Because new and delete are not part of C.

Comment: Oh that must be the case

Comment: @Dsafds Ironically, SO has the same problem. Look at the code formatting in your question. You tagged this C, yet SO decided to format those two as keywords.

Comment: Yea, @Lundin noticed that too.

Answer (score 7):

There is no `new` and `delete` keyword in `C`. It's just your editor *wrongly* identifying them as keywords and applying the [syntax highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting).

FWIW, if you have the option to control the syntax highlighting for the editor based on language (*file extension, maybe*), set it to C, even if it shows as keyword, switch to a better editor.

Just for example, see this online compiler and editor.

- [For `C` tag, it did not identify `new` and `delete` as keywords.](https://ideone.com/T0ilOI)
- [For `C++` tag, it did identify and highlight `new` and `delete` as keywords.](https://ideone.com/qJzaKc)

Comment: It shows up in the question when i type new and delete, they are all blue.. And im preety sure Visual Studio is not wrong here lol.

Comment: @Dsafds: "Visual Studio is not wrong here" -- **Visual Studio is wrong**; or badly configured, or something

Comment: @Dsafds here's a list of all the C keywords, `new` is not among them http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/list-all-keywords-c-language

Comment: The reason that must be the case is what Shiro said below. It probably thought it was a C/C++ Editor..... C and C++ Are not the same!!

Comment: @Dsafds did you tell your editor specifically that you're using [tag:c]?

Comment: @Dsafds Visual Studio is a C++ compiler. Never use it to compile C code, it is plain bad at that. I bet you have no luck with for example `restrict`, `_Bool` or `_Generic` keywords either.

Comment: @Lundin Visual Studio is an IDE for all kinds of languages. Visual C++ is the name of the compiler.

Comment: @Shiro Yea yea whatever, call it what you will, the IDE gives incorrect formatting for C code and the compiler is unable to compile standard C code correctly.

Comment: @Lundin It defaults to C (rather than C++) for .c files, but yes, unless your C standards are at least 20 years old, it might not compile standard C code correctly.